# process messages from MQ at givent time via Task

Tags: email, wso2, mq, wso2-esb

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a task in wso2 that will trigger a sequence or something else to read the stored messages and process them ?

My need here is I have at a given time to process the messages (mostly with contact informations) and after processing I need to send email to each processed contact.

What would be the best approach for this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The product you need is the [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/). It has a concept called [message processors](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Message+Processors). It can consume messages from a message store. There are two kind of message processors.

1. Message forwarding processors
2. Message sampling processors

They are quite similar. But for your purpose, message forwarding processor would be better.

After consuming the message, you can use the mail transport in WSO2 ESB to send the email to the contact. You can configure the time period for consuming messages, which is one of your main requirements.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try to dig inside the documentation.